# css li overlap the ul menu

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make menu at the top that drops down another menu it works but it overlap the menu at the top I tried absolute value but the submenu it gone I think absolute wont work and i tried relative it didnt work as well.

what is the best way to fix this?

http://jsfiddle.net/TBEnf/ Here is the Jfiddle demo

[image]

[image]

Here is my code

```
<style>
.midbox {
    margin:0px auto;
    width:900px;
    height:1000px;
    background:#c0d8d8;
    border-radius:10px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #969696;
}
.headerprofile {
    width:900px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:skyblue;
    border-top-left-radius:10px;
    border-top-right-radius:10px;
    box-shadow:0 1px -2px #70badb
}


    .headerprofile .ULlist ul li:hover > ul{
     display:block;
    }
    .headerprofile .ULlist ul ul li a {
        padding:     15px;     
        position:relative;
    }
    .headerprofile .ULlist ul ul li {
       float: none; 
    border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
    position: relative;

    }
    .headerprofile .ULlist ul ul {
        display: none;

    background: #5f6975; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
position: absolute; top: 100%;

    }
    .headerprofile .ULlist ul {
        position:relative;
        list-style:none;
        padding:0 10px;
    }

        .headerprofile .ULlist ul li {
            float:left;
        }

    .headerprofile .ULlist ul li a{

    display: block; padding: 6px 10px;
    color: #757575; text-decoration: none;

    }
```

Comment: Please post your HTML and create a jsfiddle or jsbin demo.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `position:relative` on the parent `li` instead of the outer `ul`. The `ul` doesn't have an actual height because all the `li`s are floated.

```
.headerprofile .ULlist ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0 10px;
}

    .headerprofile .ULlist ul li {
        float:left;
        position:relative;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this line will solve your problem

```
headerprofile .ULlist ul li:hover > ul
{
    display:block;
    margin-top:30px;  /* add this line to your css*/
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cDkYm/)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this if you add: `top: 30px;` to your submenu.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/HC5w3/)